# Jquery ajax with passing data into handler not working (Asp.net, C#, Jquery)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have used ajax call to passing some form data into handler with json format but the ajax is not working.
I have passes data from form Data with using **$('form').serializeArray()** and passing data using ajax call. In this scenario I have passed static data and the ajax call is still not working.

This is the jQuery code.

```
function SessionLogAutoSave() {
    var sendInfo =
    {
        "ctl00$Header1$cbo_Practice": "ea2aae16-a7f9-4e75-82b5-d2c231c97cf6",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$OFTAddRecord$hdnUrl": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$hdnSessionId": "yyuicdueevmdeynp2q12mrb1",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$hdnPracticeId": "870ee142-eb27-4d37-bba2-061fa5f801e3",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$hdnRecordId": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$hdnUserId": "d220da1a-d855-4f90-b8db-a84bc5ba8f51",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_Name": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_Address": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_ContactNumber": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$cbo_ComplaintBy": "1",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$cbo_ComplaintReceivedBy": "83beebf4-e6ea-49b3-a64f-ed20f755afdd",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$cbo_PersonHandlingComplaint": "83beebf4-e6ea-49b3-a64f-ed20f755afdd",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$cbo_Type": "1",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_ComplaintReceivedOn": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_ComplaintReceivedOn$dateInput": "",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_ComplaintReceivedOn_calendar_SD": "[]",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_ComplaintReceivedOn_calendar_AD": "[[1980,1,1],[2099,12,30],[2021,4,22]]",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_ComplaintReceivedOn_dateInput_ClientState": "{\"enabled\":true,\"emptyMessage\":\"\",\"validationText\":\"\",\"valueAsString\":\"\",\"minDateStr\":\"1980-01-01-00-00-00\",\"maxDateStr\":\"2099-12-31-00-00-00\",\"lastSetTextBoxValue\":\"\"}",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_ComplaintReceivedOn_ClientState": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_DateFollowup": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_DateFollowup$dateInput": "",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateFollowup_calendar_SD": "[]",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateFollowup_calendar_AD": "[[1980,1,1],[2099,12,30],[2021,4,22]]",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateFollowup_dateInput_ClientState": "{\"enabled\":true,\"emptyMessage\":\"\",\"validationText\":\"\",\"valueAsString\":\"\",\"minDateStr\":\"1980-01-01-00-00-00\",\"maxDateStr\":\"2099-12-31-00-00-00\",\"lastSetTextBoxValue\":\"\"}",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateFollowup_ClientState": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_DetailsComplaint": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_Followup": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_DateActionTaken": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_DateActionTaken$dateInput": "",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateActionTaken_calendar_SD": "[]",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateActionTaken_calendar_AD": "[[1980,1,1],[2099,12,30],[2021,4,22]]",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateActionTaken_dateInput_ClientState": "{\"enabled\":true,\"emptyMessage\":\"\",\"validationText\":\"\",\"valueAsString\":\"\",\"minDateStr\":\"1980-01-01-00-00-00\",\"maxDateStr\":\"2099-12-31-00-00-00\",\"lastSetTextBoxValue\":\"\"}",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateActionTaken_ClientState": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_DateOutcome": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_DateOutcome$dateInput": "",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateOutcome_calendar_SD": "[]",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateOutcome_calendar_AD": "[[1980,1,1],[2099,12,30],[2021,4,22]]",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateOutcome_dateInput_ClientState": "{\"enabled\":true,\"emptyMessage\":\"\",\"validationText\":\"\",\"valueAsString\":\"\",\"minDateStr\":\"1980-01-01-00-00-00\",\"maxDateStr\":\"2099-12-31-00-00-00\",\"lastSetTextBoxValue\":\"\"}",
        "ctl00_cph_MainContent_txt_DateOutcome_ClientState": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_ActionTaken": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$txt_Outcome": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$rbtnDiscussed": "0",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$cbo_Status": "1",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$hid_Id": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$hdnAttachments": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$hdnFileNames": "",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$cbo_Months": "4",
        "ctl00$cph_MainContent$cbo_Years": "2021"
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'Handlers/SaveSessionLogAutoSave.ashx',
        data: 'FormData=' + JSON.stringify(sendInfo) + '',
        contentType: 'application/json;utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // you can make a tiny notification here
            return;
        },
        error: function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

I have used handler for retrieve the data. My handler code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DentalCompliance.Handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SaveSessionLogAutoSave
    /// </summary>
    public class SaveSessionLogAutoSave : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string method = context.Request["FormData"];
            
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
            //}
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I searched on the internet and I have not been able to find any solutions after an 1 day of searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'Handlers/SaveSessionLogAutoSave.ashx',
            data: 'FormData=' + JSON.stringify(sendInfo) + '',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                // you can make a tiny notification here
                return;
            },
            error: function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                return;
            }
        });
```

Changed two things: 1. Type of request from **GET** to **POST** because when we use **GET**, the data you're sending appended to the URL and you're sending too much data which is exceeding the length of the URL allowed in your application.
2. Removed **contentType** because you're not sending JSON.